# how to get each rule's time cost in bazel build

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-aspect

I want to get the time every rule costs when executing a bazel build.
I found [aspect](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/aspects.html) in bazel,use that feature I can print each rule's finish time in log file.

However I found aspect of a rule executing after the rule executing, with that I can't get when a rule start executing.

So Is there any way to extend a rule before it executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bazel has builtin [performance profiling](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/performance.html#performance-profiling) which provides lots of details. Run your build with `--profile=/tmp/profile.gz` and then load the resulting file into `chrome://tracing` in any Chrome instance. You'll get something like this (from the docs):

[image: Chrome tracing view]

Note that due to [bazelbuild/bazel#12965](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/12965) you may need to manually un-gzip it before loading into Chrome.

There's also documentation on the [profile file format](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/performance.html#profile-file-format) if you want to write a tool to analyze it yourself.